# How do you determine who goes first in Android Netrunner?

Tags: android-netrunner

How do you usually determine which player goes first in Android Netrunner?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is in the rule book.

Comment: Just because an answer is in the rule book doesn't mean it is off-topic. It may make for a poor question, but that is what down-votes are for not closing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On page 12 of the [core rule book](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/android-netrunner-core-rules.pdf):

> **The Corporation always takes the first turn of the game.**